# Xcode Instruments shows my main.m file is using 80% of running time

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, instruments

I just started to using Instruments in Xcode.
I tried with tutorials and it is really great. I am having this problem with my main.m file now and i can't solve it.
I run Time Profiler and it shows that my main.m file is using 82% of running time?
When i click to check what is going on there I just get this statement colored red and marked as 100%:

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([UvodAppDelegate class]));
```

I would post a pic, but I don't have enough reputation.

Anyone some idea?

Comment: Could you post more code of main.m? Trying to see if you use recursivity.

Comment: Here is a picture1:http://s30.postimg.org/p8bvzqqip/Screen_Shot_2014_10_10_at_20_57_43.png

Comment: Here is picture2:http://s22.postimg.org/yg8e3zy4h/Screen_Shot_2014_10_10_at_20_59_53.png

Comment: @VAndrei : Look at my comments.. there is print screen of my main.m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the images you provided, it is normal to have high CPU utilization in the main line.

This line creates the application object singleton and starts the main event loop.

If in your application you implement for example a compute intensive function it will show up in the profiler stats.

Comment: So everything is ok than if I understand you correctly? Because I have some issues with my app, sometimes it just not running smooth for a really short time like less than a second and i was wondering if my main.m file is problem..

Comment: The problem is not in the main.m file. If appears that you don't have many events that make much use of the CPU.